# Scaling actual running time of the program to the theoretical running time

Tags: performance, big-o, theory

I have obtained running time of my program (CPU time) in seconds for different input sizes and I want to build a chart showing CPU time and theoretical running time (for example `O(n³)`).

How should I scale CPU time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU time and BigO notation are two different things, so they should not be compared.

The idea behind BigO notation is that it gives you a platform independent way of gauging the efficiency of an algorithm.  Different algorithms will run in different times on different CPUs depending on speed, load, etc... of the CPU.  Therefore, the CPU is not a good metric.  The question with any algorithm is whether it's written as efficiently as possible.

This is where BigO notation comes in.  It measures the number of operations required to accomplish a task, and as such is platform independent.  If you reduce the number of operations required to complete a task, then -- all else remaining equal -- you will improve your efficiency, regardless of platform.

Therefore, count the number of operations in the program and derive the BigO complexity from that.  Then you can measure it against the theoretical.